# How to make VM routable from home network

Tags: networking, routing, qemu, kvm-switch

I have 3 guest OS on KVM/QEMU, all of them can connect to each other as well as the host. But my phone (home network) cannot access it. How do i make it routable from home network?

Details ->

- Home network : 192.168.1.0/24
- Home router gateway : 192.168.1.1
- Host IP : 192.168.1.248 (my pc)
- Guest network : 192.168.100.0/24
- Guest gateway : 192.168.100.1 (my pc)
- Guest 1 IP : 192.168.100.234
- Guest 2 IP : 192.168.100.123
- Guest 3 IP : 192.168.100.150

Comment: The easiest way to to put the Guest Machines on the same subnet as the host machines.  In my virtual world, this is called Bridged Networking. Works fine.

Comment: @John when i set the guest to the same subnet as the host i got an error -> Error creating virtual network: internal error: Network is already in use by interface enp27s0

Comment: Maybe try a better virtualizing app. I do not get errors like this with VMware.

Comment: nvm, i figured it out now. setting the guest the same subnet with the host. thanks for your help

Comment: If I post the subnetting answer, will you find that helpful?